# Application download doesn't start

Tags: android

I am trying to install Angry Birds from Android market on my HTC Desire A8181. But surprisingly the download doesn't start. All I get is **Starting Download** which never actually starts. This holds for every application.
I followed [this](https://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=113409) to download the app from market.
Also if I get any application from **Bluetooth** from some other device, will it successfully run on my phone?

Comment: Same case here in HTC Hero, showing "Starting Download" but download never starts.

Comment: Check firewall settings if you are using WiFi. And yes you can use an application which you get from other device. check it out http://www.simplehelp.net/2011/01/05/how-to-install-apk-files-on-your-android-device/

Answer (score 0):

while downloading the application make sure that your gtalk is logged in . Market for some reason needs the gtalk to be logged in , in order to start the download. So if its still showing "starting download" minimize the market and tap on gtalk , works for me .